# Visual Studio, PHP, Xdebug: Error evaluating code while debugging

Tags: php, visual-studio, xdebug

My Visual Studio debugger is not working properly and I get "*Error evaluating code*" for everything (see the variable value, 1+1, and any other PHP code).
All fixes are not working.

I tried with:

VS 2017/2019/2022

PHP 7.4, PHP8.0, PHP 8.1, PHP 8.2

I tried multiple configurations of php.ini

I'm using XAMPP 3.3.0 on W10.

Xdebug log show errors like this when I try to run any PHP code in the immediate window:

```
[8796] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 16-0 -- ZXZhbCgidHJ5IHsgcmV0dXJuICAxICsgMTsgfWNhdGNoIChUaHJvd2FibGUgJHQpeyByZXR1cm4gbmV3IERldnNlbnNlRXZhbEVycm9yKCR0LT5nZXRNZXNzYWdlKCkpO31jYXRjaCAoRXhjZXB0aW9uICRlKXsgcmV0dXJuIG5ldyBEZXZzZW5zZUV2YWxFcnJvcigkZS0+Z2V0TWVzc2FnZSgpKTt9Iik7
[8796] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="16-0" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>
```

I'm trying to solve this issue by 1 year. No success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base64 decode of that string results in:

```
eval("try { return  1 + 1; }catch (Throwable $t){ return new DevsenseEvalError($t->getMessage());}catch (Exception $e){ return new DevsenseEvalError($e->getMessage());}");
```

Which can't really work, as you haven't escaped the `$t` in `catch (Throwable $t)` for example, and that throws a warning and a parse error when you run this with normal PHP:

```
Warning: Undefined variable $t in /tmp/foo.php on line 2

Warning: Undefined variable $t in /tmp/foo.php on line 2

Warning: Attempt to read property "getMessage" on null in /tmp/foo.php on line 2

Warning: Undefined variable $e in /tmp/foo.php on line 2

Warning: Undefined variable $e in /tmp/foo.php on line 2

Warning: Attempt to read property "getMessage" on null in /tmp/foo.php on line 2

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token ")" in /tmp/foo.php(2) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

It seems likely that Devsense (I don't know what that is) is throwing a spanner in the works, as it literally just should send `MSsx` (base 64 encoded form of `1+1`).

Comment: I just typed 1 + 1 in immediate window. The other code (try { ... }...) is added by Visual Studio or PHP tools. Are you telling this? The bug is from Visual Studio or PHP Tools? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, exactly. I only have VS Code + "PHP Debug" and "PHP Extension Pack" installed, and that generates: `eval -i 14 -- JEdMT0JBTFNbJ2V2YWxfY2FjaGUnXVsnNjQyZTAxNDUtYzFmYS00YjdmLWFjZDAtZDhlYjExYTZlY2JhJ109MSsx` which translates to a **correct** `$GLOBALS['eval_cache']['642e0145-c1fa-4b7f-acd0-d8eb11a6ecba']=1+1`.

Comment: I have the same issue you described I contacted Devsense and Devtools. Thanks!

Comment: yes, that's our bug(Devsense) introduced in a recent version. Sorry about that! The fixed version is available now